# Azure LogAnalytics Scopes KQL

Tags: m, azure-log-analytics, kql

It does not seem to be possible to export a KQL query that includes multiple scopes to a Power BI M query in the Azure Monitor environment. I wonder if there is another way to still be able to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance,

D

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing something but based on the understanding and as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-powerbi) document, Log Analytics queries can be exported to M and used in Power BI directly.

[image]

Comment: Yes that Is correct, but unfortunately you can't select multiple scopes in one query